# Android Spinner Display Text Issue

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Hi im having a issue with text size not displaying correctly on my activity, the drop down it self is large(bottom picture) which is how i want it however when the drop down is not open it has small text(top picture). here is the xml layout the spinner pulls from

```
simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

and here is the xml of the menu in which the spinner is displayed on

```
main_menu.xml
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerMainMenu"
    android:layout_width="784dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.072"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
```

and finally the code for how it is displayed

```
MainMenu.java
final Spinner mainMenuDrpDwn = findViewById(R.id.spinnerMainMenu);
    String[] machines = new String[]{"215 DT", "420 DT", "215 CANNAGIN"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, machines);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mainMenuDrpDwn.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this let us understand the Adapter concept in a bit detail, the adapter which binds the spinner's layout files and the data to the spinner takes in two layout files. One is the **layout resource** which you passed in during the initialization of the `ArrayAdapter` i.e.,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, machines);
```

This is the layout resource for the spinner when it is in not expanded state i.e. spinner items are shown. The other is the **dropdown resource** which is the layout of the drop down items of the spinners i.e. how each item in the spinner will look when it is expanded, it is set as follows:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Now the problem is that you are passing in a custom `dropdown resource` so you are getting the dropdown to look as desired but you are passing in the standard layout file for the view i.e. `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`. So to resolve this if you want you can pass in the same dropdown resource for the normal view too (if you wish to do so) else you can create another layout with the desired properties and pass that it as done in the following code:

**custom_drop_down_spinner_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"/>
```

**custom_spinner_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text2"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

setting it to the spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.educational_qualification_orig_array, R.layout.custom_spinner_item);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_drop_down_spinner_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

The resulting spinner item in unexpanded state would look like

[image: Custom spinner item]

Comment: Thank you so much, for me since iam using a sting as the text that gets displayed i had to edit your adapter code to fit. ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, machines)

Answer (score 1):

Use the same layout file in your adapter.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, machines);
```

It will only work if your `TextView` id is `text1` on your `simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml`

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on **dr3k**'s answer, I found this in the source:

http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml

```
4742    <declare-styleable name="Spinner">
...
4763        <!-- Reference to a layout to use for displaying a prompt in the dropdown for
4764             spinnerMode="dropdown". This layout must contain a TextView with the id
4765             {@code @android:id/text1} to be populated with the prompt text. -->
4766        <attr name="popupPromptView" format="reference" />
...
4772    </declare-styleable>
```